# Sizing table to page

Tags: tables, csvsimple

Apologies for a general question but I need some help strategizing about how to include a fairly large amount of data in an article document.

Basically I have several 35x35 matrices that I need to include in a document.

using:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\tiny
\csvautotabular{actual_flows.csv}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

I've gotten about 20 columns onto a single page but it doesn't seem like I'm going to be able to get the rest of the table onto the page.

Is there a way I can use csvautotabular and start compressing whitespace in the table or does that require using `\csvreader{}` instead?

Is really the only solution to split the table across two pages?

Are there general style guidelines for this type of thing?

here's the output from calc2latex in case that's helpful

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Actual Flows between boroughs}
\begin{tabular} 
{|r|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & Borough & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 \\ \hline
1 & Barking & 0 & 194 & 96 & 178 & 66 & 1500 & 3641 & 104 & 188 & 410 & 209 & 980 & 255 & 301 & 55 & 6415 & 97 & 91 & 1385 & 439 & 18 & 449 & 132 & 67 & 4460 & 5940 & 28 & 926 & 38 & 4069 & 1047 & 165 & 3280 & 37223 \\ \hline
2 & Barnet & 96 & 0 & 34 & 5467 & 76 & 12080 & 7709 & 148 & 1573 & 4098 & 101 & 1576 & 1431 & 3842 & 2623 & 131 & 1023 & 611 & 5775 & 1841 & 68 & 1129 & 124 & 146 & 387 & 305 & 229 & 1792 & 44 & 2511 & 555 & 536 & 16330 & 74391 \\ \hline
3 & Bexley & 362 & 132 & 0 & 144 & 4998 & 2470 & 6580 & 710 & 188 & 123 & 9498 & 698 & 333 & 110 & 29 & 394 & 109 & 161 & 1557 & 603 & 77 & 1808 & 2989 & 190 & 574 & 111 & 90 & 4666 & 170 & 2825 & 222 & 618 & 7692 & 51231 \\ \hline
4 & Brent & 40 & 6124 & 28 & 0 & 66 & 8105 & 4145 & 187 & 6703 & 426 & 124 & 809 & 3709 & 730 & 5102 & 51 & 2127 & 1404 & 2535 & 3926 & 116 & 1107 & 147 & 203 & 279 & 116 & 396 & 1565 & 56 & 1655 & 210 & 669 & 16418 & 69278 \\ \hline
5 & Bromley & 134 & 162 & 3199 & 201 & 0 & 3780 & 9855 & 6268 & 293 & 84 & 2586 & 728 & 859 & 134 & 59 & 119 & 248 & 285 & 2094 & 1241 & 227 & 3570 & 5360 & 647 & 419 & 100 & 191 & 6057 & 796 & 3385 & 196 & 1371 & 12802 & 67450 \\ \hline
6 & Camden & 36 & 1496 & 32 & 1350 & 60 & 0 & 8795 & 147 & 643 & 295 & 140 & 1201 & 1870 & 666 & 330 & 43 & 473 & 473 & 4987 & 2267 & 89 & 1338 & 140 & 139 & 290 & 84 & 195 & 1784 & 54 & 2614 & 204 & 588 & 18829 & 51652 \\ \hline
7 & City & 6 & 14 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 335 & 0 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 66 & 61 & 16 & 7 & 9 & 10 & 9 & 339 & 62 & 0 & 42 & 15 & 6 & 16 & 0 & 6 & 103 & 3 & 266 & 16 & 16 & 602 & 2062 \\ \hline
8 & Croydon & 85 & 204 & 300 & 329 & 5152 & 3248 & 5925 & 0 & 405 & 120 & 523 & 599 & 1284 & 177 & 97 & 82 & 457 & 581 & 1752 & 1478 & 827 & 6844 & 1563 & 3521 & 202 & 64 & 480 & 4513 & 6744 & 2000 & 130 & 4270 & 10583 & 64539 \\ \hline
9 & Ealing & 30 & 967 & 33 & 5263 & 91 & 4547 & 4855 & 182 & 0 & 223 & 136 & 522 & 8579 & 267 & 2601 & 48 & 13055 & 9869 & 1795 & 4111 & 364 & 1031 & 174 & 361 & 229 & 79 & 1578 & 1328 & 65 & 1420 & 127 & 944 & 13967 & 78841 \\ \hline
10 & Enfield & 217 & 5642 & 52 & 1038 & 76 & 5588 & 5212 & 136 & 626 & 0 & 126 & 2542 & 850 & 10199 & 328 & 233 & 457 & 339 & 5317 & 1091 & 38 & 806 & 114 & 114 & 661 & 538 & 98 & 1253 & 47 & 2141 & 1710 & 314 & 9052 & 56955 \\ \hline
11 & Greenwich & 333 & 181 & 5046 & 252 & 3196 & 3038 & 5614 & 692 & 248 & 192 & 0 & 856 & 607 & 178 & 45 & 147 & 154 & 233 & 1780 & 929 & 58 & 2292 & 5571 & 237 & 981 & 126 & 113 & 5145 & 134 & 3643 & 244 & 940 & 8847 & 52052 \\ \hline
12 & Hackney & 222 & 687 & 56 & 514 & 90 & 7137 & 5181 & 128 & 450 & 877 & 241 & 0 & 1165 & 2335 & 92 & 124 & 203 & 283 & 7740 & 1261 & 61 & 1269 & 240 & 121 & 1069 & 402 & 149 & 2023 & 58 & 5247 & 1101 & 567 & 9983 & 51076 \\ \hline
13 & Fulham & 25 & 259 & 19 & 812 & 56 & 4009 & 7967 & 202 & 2418 & 82 & 63 & 586 & 0 & 137 & 163 & 33 & 1090 & 2097 & 1795 & 7072 & 271 & 1153 & 122 & 466 & 123 & 33 & 854 & 1374 & 113 & 1947 & 66 & 1908 & 15305 & 52620 \\ \hline
14 & Haringey & 144 & 3016 & 32 & 1074 & 64 & 10506 & 5523 & 213 & 668 & 4249 & 154 & 3130 & 1486 & 0 & 268 & 99 & 330 & 450 & 7948 & 1889 & 67 & 1236 & 178 & 136 & 520 & 278 & 180 & 1857 & 48 & 2350 & 1004 & 507 & 13479 & 63083 \\ \hline
15 & Harrow & 55 & 5008 & 26 & 9473 & 47 & 3675 & 3162 & 103 & 4542 & 325 & 62 & 430 & 1487 & 331 & 0 & 29 & 6169 & 1141 & 1395 & 1160 & 107 & 501 & 71 & 119 & 99 & 44 & 246 & 854 & 34 & 1013 & 95 & 300 & 7882 & 49985 \\ \hline
16 & Havering & 7278 & 194 & 325 & 156 & 157 & 2001 & 8348 & 131 & 165 & 546 & 260 & 1302 & 260 & 335 & 69 & 0 & 116 & 83 & 1932 & 358 & 33 & 552 & 137 & 85 & 3410 & 4844 & 45 & 1389 & 50 & 5030 & 1173 & 158 & 4699 & 45621 \\ \hline
17 & Hillingdon & 31 & 692 & 18 & 2672 & 55 & 1757 & 1661 & 116 & 8185 & 153 & 49 & 205 & 1799 & 110 & 4688 & 21 & 0 & 5293 & 664 & 925 & 150 & 401 & 79 & 167 & 83 & 35 & 548 & 511 & 58 & 565 & 53 & 248 & 5062 & 37054 \\ \hline
18 & Hounslow & 19 & 253 & 27 & 807 & 69 & 1753 & 2342 & 215 & 5488 & 92 & 106 & 250 & 3587 & 87 & 396 & 28 & 12803 & 0 & 752 & 1800 & 1006 & 692 & 128 & 303 & 100 & 31 & 7025 & 657 & 101 & 753 & 41 & 765 & 5927 & 48403 \\ \hline
19 & Islington & 110 & 1001 & 46 & 538 & 46 & 10188 & 7931 & 157 & 479 & 619 & 138 & 2758 & 1473 & 1869 & 111 & 55 & 265 & 334 & 0 & 1672 & 50 & 1191 & 152 & 131 & 348 & 117 & 118 & 1883 & 56 & 2837 & 393 & 490 & 12835 & 50391 \\ \hline
20 & K and C & 22 & 232 & 20 & 548 & 64 & 3554 & 10098 & 165 & 861 & 48 & 54 & 445 & 3679 & 123 & 106 & 18 & 576 & 788 & 1816 & 0 & 112 & 1029 & 78 & 208 & 68 & 30 & 300 & 1168 & 67 & 2957 & 68 & 1085 & 15947 & 46334 \\ \hline
21 & Kingston & 9 & 104 & 35 & 184 & 72 & 1547 & 2875 & 638 & 469 & 42 & 58 & 176 & 1327 & 32 & 68 & 24 & 1070 & 1484 & 710 & 847 & 0 & 1028 & 70 & 3041 & 71 & 31 & 3788 & 1038 & 1190 & 825 & 20 & 2395 & 5419 & 30687 \\ \hline
22 & Lambeth & 64 & 406 & 136 & 477 & 826 & 8090 & 9697 & 3143 & 667 & 150 & 595 & 1469 & 3376 & 373 & 89 & 49 & 466 & 898 & 4149 & 4368 & 527 & 0 & 1344 & 1830 & 380 & 123 & 855 & 8267 & 803 & 3414 & 185 & 8028 & 24349 & 89593 \\ \hline
23 & Lewisham & 164 & 271 & 1170 & 332 & 6677 & 4963 & 7251 & 2457 & 457 & 133 & 4555 & 1231 & 1114 & 277 & 83 & 93 & 238 & 365 & 2669 & 1791 & 181 & 5685 & 0 & 583 & 657 & 141 & 259 & 11118 & 406 & 3949 & 236 & 1901 & 13727 & 75134 \\ \hline
24 & Merton & 34 & 181 & 56 & 251 & 316 & 2952 & 6051 & 3193 & 554 & 49 & 176 & 454 & 2310 & 143 & 68 & 20 & 532 & 848 & 1411 & 2223 & 3516 & 3383 & 250 & 0 & 157 & 31 & 1334 & 2282 & 3743 & 1704 & 81 & 8410 & 10148 & 56861 \\ \hline
25 & Newham & 2702 & 401 & 147 & 513 & 207 & 3855 & 5009 & 190 & 431 & 584 & 735 & 2397 & 741 & 675 & 57 & 934 & 207 & 283 & 2709 & 1497 & 86 & 1154 & 386 & 139 & 0 & 2969 & 126 & 2089 & 56 & 9120 & 2161 & 534 & 8565 & 51659 \\ \hline
26 & Redbridge & 4664 & 567 & 141 & 386 & 132 & 3790 & 8205 & 173 & 343 & 1187 & 330 & 2338 & 581 & 906 & 110 & 3004 & 212 & 231 & 3104 & 746 & 46 & 853 & 188 & 100 & 6031 & 0 & 88 & 1760 & 48 & 6916 & 5441 & 262 & 8122 & 61005 \\ \hline
27 & Richmond & 15 & 173 & 12 & 342 & 64 & 2504 & 4831 & 323 & 1469 & 41 & 64 & 276 & 3181 & 53 & 167 & 20 & 3365 & 6873 & 1002 & 1745 & 3549 & 1216 & 84 & 840 & 65 & 12 & 0 & 1213 & 260 & 1197 & 46 & 1991 & 8336 & 45329 \\ \hline
28 & Southwark & 108 & 319 & 281 & 428 & 933 & 6003 & 9041 & 1213 & 536 & 135 & 1138 & 1401 & 1682 & 271 & 123 & 74 & 312 & 466 & 3203 & 2552 & 273 & 8500 & 3163 & 566 & 580 & 161 & 313 & 0 & 261 & 4243 & 251 & 2545 & 16500 & 67575 \\ \hline
29 & Sutton & 33 & 81 & 68 & 138 & 514 & 1450 & 2560 & 7602 & 309 & 45 & 101 & 230 & 851 & 51 & 50 & 23 & 385 & 541 & 681 & 882 & 3122 & 1827 & 270 & 6725 & 95 & 26 & 750 & 1404 & 0 & 872 & 41 & 3217 & 4691 & 39635 \\ \hline
30 & Tower Hamlets & 370 & 257 & 140 & 192 & 192 & 4080 & 10104 & 183 & 291 & 224 & 275 & 2668 & 935 & 326 & 56 & 304 & 146 & 245 & 3235 & 1249 & 58 & 1090 & 316 & 124 & 1845 & 407 & 151 & 2182 & 55 & 0 & 562 & 405 & 9304 & 41971 \\ \hline
31 & Waltham Forest & 846 & 715 & 79 & 491 & 149 & 5554 & 6337 & 253 & 440 & 2661 & 337 & 3957 & 832 & 2467 & 112 & 594 & 206 & 271 & 4310 & 1378 & 50 & 1059 & 228 & 122 & 3257 & 3736 & 101 & 1719 & 41 & 4789 & 0 & 409 & 10314 & 57814 \\ \hline
32 & Wandsworth & 34 & 297 & 69 & 422 & 324 & 7140 & 13935 & 1496 & 970 & 116 & 256 & 1044 & 6232 & 225 & 129 & 31 & 853 & 1690 & 3404 & 6208 & 1806 & 5951 & 403 & 4329 & 208 & 59 & 2338 & 4092 & 992 & 4024 & 135 & 0 & 24409 & 93621 \\ \hline
33 & Westminster & 25 & 514 & 17 & 1229 & 99 & 6786 & 9521 & 216 & 925 & 121 & 93 & 745 & 2369 & 228 & 142 & 26 & 597 & 572 & 2442 & 4767 & 90 & 1381 & 148 & 178 & 170 & 60 & 258 & 1663 & 61 & 2851 & 121 & 873 & 0 & 39288 \\ \hline
34 & (all) & 18313 & 30744 & 11740 & 36217 & 24934 & 147985 & 209961 & 31087 & 41993 & 18456 & 23286 & 38069 & 60305 & 27974 & 18423 & 13275 & 48351 & 39292 & 
86387 & 64378 & 17043 & 61567 & 24364 & 25944 & 27834 & 21033 & 23230 & 79675 & 
16652 & 93132 & 17935 & 47429 & 353405 & 1800413 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{Actual Flows}
\end{table}
```

and here's the document info:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{array} % for better arrays (eg matrices) in maths
\usepackage{paralist} % very flexible & customisable lists (eg. enumerate/itemize, etc.)
\usepackage{verbatim} % adds environment for commenting out blocks of text & for better verbatim
\usepackage{subfig} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages? How much of the table can fit onto a page depends on the documentclass and the margin settings. Would rotating the table be an option for you?

Comment: In order to remove some of th e horizontal white space, you could use something like `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}` or any other length smaller than the default of  6pt. In order to save some more horizontal space you could also remove the second column and add  the information in a legend below the table.

Comment: thanks I'll explore both of those. Added document settings to question.

Comment: Having had a closer look at your table, I am quite sure that you will not be able to fit the whole table onto a single page. Removing horizontal white space in combination with a very small font size and smaller margins will still not allow the table to fit. I would therefore recommend to split it onto two or even three portait pages.